# How to make this file input 'not required' in jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which contains a file input element. I have not set its required to true. Still, it is telling me to select a file. The message reads "This field is required". I dont want jquery to validate it. Here is what I have done.

jQuery validate rules and messages:

```
$.validator.addMethod("file_size_validator", function(value, element) {

    var flag;
    if($(element)[0].files[0].size > 2048000 || $(element)[0].files[1].size > 2048000 || $(element)[0].files[2].size > 2048000){
      flag = false;
    } else{
      flag = true;
    }

   return flag;
  }, "Any file's size should not exceed 2MB");


img: {
        extension: "png|jpg|jpeg",
        file_size_validator: true,
      },

img: {
        extension: 'File should of jpg or jpeg or png extension',
      },


<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label style="padding-left:20px;padding-top:10px">Upload images<strong> (Upto 3 images only)<strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" id="uploaded_files" required="required" multiple>
                </div>
</div>
```

When I enter a file; it works fine. It validates the file. However, when I dont select any file. Then it should not validate this element however it still validates the input file element. It even doesnt work if I supply "required: false" as a rule to img. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a form which contains a file input element. I have not set its required to true. Still, it is telling me to select a file.

That's because you have the `required` attribute within the HTML...

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="files[]" id="uploaded_files" required="required" multiple>
```

Remove the `required="required"` attribute.

---

The jQuery Validate plugin will set a field to `required` if any one of the following are true...

- You've declared the `required` rule on the field within the `rules` object of the `.validate()` method.
- You've declared the `required` rule on the field within the `.rules()` method.
- You have a `required` class on the field element.
- **You have a `required` attribute on the field element.**
- You've created a compound rule that included the `required` rule using the `jQuery.validator.addClassRules()` method, and assigned this class to the field element.

Comment: Cant believe how I made this mistake!! Arrrrrrrrgh!!

Comment: Yeah I also had `required=true` without an explicit JS registration. This was triggering the validation. thanks.